# Dojo Gauge and Value

Tags: dojo

I have a gauge example

```
model = new Stateful({value: 20});

div data-dojo-type="bulletgraph/BulletGraph" id="gauge" style="height:60px"
                 data-dojo-props="value: at(model,'value'), target: 100, low: 0, medium: 0, high: 100"
```

but the `value` should be the value as a function onMessage

```
function onMessage(evt) 
var page = JSON.parse(evt.data); 
page.Value.toFixed(1)
```

How can I set `page.Value.toFixed(1)` to `data-dojo-props="value: at(model,'value')`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to proceed one would be in your onMessage function to update the model object with the result of your parsing/toFixed call?

Some as follows:

```
function onMessage(evt){
   model.set("value", page.Value.toFixed(1));
}
```